# Fastlane scan fail testing and complains about "missing Umbrella headers" (iOS)

Tags: ios, header, fastlane

I'm using fastalane v.2.45.0
my project contains two pods: **BRYXBanner** and **Alamofire**.

scan is failing with the following error:

```
 Testing failed:
 Umbrella header 'BRYXBanner-umbrella.h' not found
 Could not build Objective-C module 'BRYXBanner'
 Umbrella header 'Alamofire-umbrella.h' not found
 Could not build Objective-C module 'Alamofire'
 ** TEST FAILED **
```

the command inside my Fastfile is:

```
`scan(workspace:"MyProject.xcworkspace",scheme:"MyProject Dev",devices:["iPhone 7"])`
```

Here's the output of `fastlane env`:

````
### Loaded fastlane plugins:

```
**No plugins Loaded**


<details><summary><b>Loaded gems</b></summary>

| Gem                       | Version      |
| ------------------------- | ------------ |
| did_you_mean              | 1.1.0        |
| slack-notifier            | 1.5.1        |
| CFPropertyList            | 2.3.4        |
| claide                    | 1.0.1        |
| colored2                  | 3.1.1        |
| nanaimo                   | 0.2.3        |
| xcodeproj                 | 1.4.4        |
| rouge                     | 1.11.1       |
| xcpretty                  | 0.2.4        |
| terminal-notifier         | 1.7.1        |
| unicode-display_width     | 1.1.3        |
| terminal-table            | 1.7.3        |
| plist                     | 3.2.0        |
| multipart-post            | 2.0.0        |
| word_wrap                 | 1.0.0        |
| tty-screen                | 0.5.0        |
| babosa                    | 1.0.2        |
| colored                   | 1.2          |
| highline                  | 1.7.8        |
| commander-fastlane        | 4.4.5        |
| excon                     | 0.54.0       |
| faraday                   | 0.11.0       |
| unf_ext                   | 0.0.7.2      |
| unf                       | 0.1.4        |
| domain_name               | 0.5.20161129 |
| http-cookie               | 1.0.3        |
| faraday-cookie_jar        | 0.0.6        |
| fastimage                 | 2.1.0        |
| gh_inspector              | 1.0.3        |
| uber                      | 0.0.15       |
| declarative               | 0.0.9        |
| declarative-option        | 0.1.0        |
| representable             | 3.0.4        |
| retriable                 | 2.1.0        |
| public_suffix             | 2.0.5        |
| addressable               | 2.5.1        |
| mime-types-data           | 3.2016.0521  |
| mime-types                | 3.1          |
| little-plugger            | 1.1.4        |
| multi_json                | 1.12.1       |
| logging                   | 2.1.0        |
| jwt                       | 1.5.6        |
| memoist                   | 0.15.0       |
| os                        | 0.9.6        |
| signet                    | 0.7.3        |
| googleauth                | 0.5.1        |
| httpclient                | 2.8.3        |
| google-api-client         | 0.12.0       |
| mini_magick               | 4.5.1        |
| multi_xml                 | 0.6.0        |
| rubyzip                   | 1.2.0        |
| security                  | 0.1.3        |
| xcpretty-travis-formatter | 0.0.4        |
| dotenv                    | 2.1.2        |
| bundler                   | 1.13.7       |
| faraday_middleware        | 0.11.0       |
| json                      | 2.0.2        |
| io-console                | 0.4.6        |
| openssl                   | 2.0.2        |
````

Comment: Are you able to run the tests from Xcode in the "MyProject Dev" scheme? Does it build with Command-Shift-U?

Comment: Yes, they run without problems

Comment: The failures to find header files is a red flag for me. Can you find the `xcodebuild ... test` line and run it from the command line without any issues? Additionally, `scan` will output where the logs are like so: `IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test session to:` Review that log for any hints.

Comment: My point is that this does not look like a `fastlane` issue